# How to express this pattern with java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on a java program that tries extracts a string with the format:

```
|something|=
```

from different string inputs, where |something| has the following constraints:

> 1. |something| can not start with "*"
> 2. |something| can not be equal to "name"
> 3. |something| can have any length

Can such pattern be represented with a java regular expression? Or should I consider a different approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regular expression you can use:

```
\|(?!name\|)[^*].*\|=
```

You can get a nice explanation [here](http://regex101.com/r/mG4kM5/1).

Comment: since you have at least one character you can use this fact to exclude the `*`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, not really - he doesn't want to match anything that starts with *

Comment: Yes I know but you can remove it from the lookahead and write `[^|*][^|]*`

Comment: he doesn't say `something` can't contain pipes, only that start/end must be pipes. perhaps `[^*].*` is enough for the content